# After adding lazy load in existing app, style is not working

Tags: css, angular

In my existing app I add lazy loading module... 
first I have this structure

```
app.component.ts
app.component.css
app.component.html
app-routing.module.ts
app.module.ts
 |
 |-nav
 |  |-nav.component.ts
 |  |-nav.component.html
 |  |-nav.component.css
 |
 |-users
 |    |-user.component.ts
 |    |-user.component.html
 |    |-user.component.css
 |             |
 |             |-add
 |                |-add.component.ts
 |                |-add.component.html
 |                |-add.component.css
 |
 |-tests
 |    |-test.component.ts
 |    |-test.component.html
 |    |-test.component.css
 |             |
 |             |-add
 |                |-add.component.ts
 |                |-add.component.html
 |                |-add.component.cs
```

And in `USERS` and in `TESTS` I add `module.ts` and `routing-module.ts` and lazy loading everything.
And this works in a proper way.

**1. Question**

Now any of this `CSS` in this component not working (nav.component.css, user.component.css, add.component.css, test.component.css...)

When I inspect element in the console I see the property but it is crossed.

[image]

**2. Question**

I didn't add the module to add.component.ts because it is called on click, or do I need lazy load this too?

Thank you

Comment: a crossed style usually means you have it defined twice... have a look on the `computed` tab of your browser's dev tools for css and you can figure where this color override is coming from

Comment: I have an original style in material indigo.css, and here I want to rewrite with this... but same is with every property i try

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the problem, the problem is not in CSS but in `flex-layout`.

I separate modules in the core, shared, etc module... 
And I put `flex-layout` in the shared module, but I forget export it